# TypeError: promise.then is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs5

Using Rxjs v5, trying to run http.get requests in sequential order but getting error `TypeError: promise.then is not a function`
js code:

```
    var http = require('http');
    Rx.Observable
        .from(data)
        .pairwise()
        .concatMap(a => {
            var url = 'http://to/some/api?origins=' + a[0].lat + ',' + a[0].lng + '&destinations=' + a[1].lat + ',' + a[1].lng;
            return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(http.get(url));        
        })    
        .subscribe(item => {
            console.log(item);
        });
```

Comment: [`http.get`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) doesn't return a Promise. It returns an event handler.

Comment: so any alternate method?

Comment: You don't need the wrapper of `fromPromise` just return `http.get(url)` directly.

Comment: return http.get(url) directly throws another error TypeError: unknown type returned

Comment: Nvm, I didn't realize that the node `http.get` method follows some odd semantics, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The node `http.get` method does not return a promise, see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)

It actually uses a rather non-standard interface (at least I haven't really seen it before), so to get this working you need a small custom work-around instead (**note**: this is a relatively naive implementation):

```
var http = require('http');
function observableGet(options) {
  return new Rx.Observable(subscriber => {
    var subscription = new Rx.Subscription();

    //Create the request
    var request = http.get(options, (res) => {
      //Create a stream for the "end" event
      var done = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(res, 'end');

      //Create a stream for data events
      var s1 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(res, 'data')
        //Take data events until all have been read
        .takeUntil(done)
        //Gather all the data events into a single object
        .reduce((body, delta) => body + delta, '')
        //Optional: Parse the resulting data object
        .map(x => JSON.parse(x))
        //Start the stream
        .subscribe(subscriber);

      //Register this stream for disposal
      subscription.add(s1);
    });

    //Grab errors from the request and forward them to the error handler
    //of subscriber
    var s2 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(request, 'error', (e) => { throw e; })
      .subscribe(subscriber);

    //Register for disposal
    subscription.add(s2);

    //Return the parent subscription
    return subscription;
  });
}
```

Then you can use it in place of `http.get`

```
    Rx.Observable
    .from(data)
    .pairwise()
    .concatMap(a => {
        var url = //...url;
        return observableGet(url);        
    })    
    .subscribe(item => {
        console.log(item);
    });
```

Alternatively you could use a library that returns `Promises` instead, which might make your life easier, i.e. [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)